# How can I create a layout with tabs completely in XML?

Tags: android, xml, layout, tabs

I'm trying to make tabs in a layout. I've found a lot of examples and tutorials using `TabWidget`, `TabHost`, but they all involve one of the following:

- Java code in the activity
- Separate activities for each tabs
- Separate fragments for each tabs

The content inside the tabs is static, so I should just be able to include everything in the layout, in pure XML.

Anyway to do that?

Comment: You're going to have to have some code at some point-  the xml isn't going to know how to switch when a tab is clicked and what to do when that happens.  You can avoid something as heavy as activities/fragments, but its not going to be codeless.

Answer (score 13):

The simple answer, no.  You have to setup your `TabHost` in Java code and create your tabs.  You can have static layouts for the tabs without using fragments but it still requires setup in Java.

If you don't do this setup in code, your `TabWidget` won't know which layout corresponds to which tab and wouldn't be able to function.  You're going to have to write a bit of code.

The code for doing this is really simple though.

The XML (placed inside your layout where you want it):

```
<TabHost android:id="@+id/tab_host"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_one_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_two_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The Java code (placed wherever you setup your layout):

```
TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
host.setup();

TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_one_container);
spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
host.addTab(spec);

spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_two_container);
spec.setIndicator("Tab Two");
host.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: That kind of sucks. Why cant I reference the id of the layout in the tab to connect them?

I don't mind writing code, but I feel like having to put that links in the code is out of place.

Comment: You can't do it because Google hasn't written it into the SDK.  I wish I had a better answer for you but when you work with someone else's framework then you're subjected to the limitations they put in place.  This just happens to be one of those limitations.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the best I found is this:

https://gist.github.com/jerolimov/618086

It still involves Java code, but there is no duplication of structure in the code, everything is in XML.